# Please delete my duplicate question even though it has an answer?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked a question on my cell phone which was very poorly received.

The question is very clear in my opinion but it is a duplicate and the answer in retrospective is so obvious, I am embarrassed for asking it.

I cannot delete it because someone answered it.

I do not think it is worth adding context to the question because it is a duplicate.

I would appreciate if a moderator would delete the question that I asked today.

Thanks very much,

-Larry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question was so standard that

- another user had already located an exact duplicate, so I simply voted to close your question as a dup,
- and then I merged it with the duplicate target, relocating the answer.

With the upvoted answer conveniently out of the way you should now be able to delete it. Be more careful next time!

---

Edit: It turned out that regular users cannot delete the stub left behind after a merger. This one is gone anyway.

Comment: Thanks!  Lesson learned.  I get so excited about patterns that I discover.    Going forward, I will think on questions at least 1-2 hours before posting.  Regards.

Comment: I rather doubt OP can delete it now. A stub is I think like a locked post.

Comment: That may well be, quid (I don't know). @Larry, are you now able to delete it?

Comment: I am not able to delete it.

Comment: Ok, so @quid was right. Let me try... Gone.

Comment: @LarryFreeman that's a great idea! I for one try to think about questions for at least a day or two before posting but that's a matter of perspective i guess. :D

Comment: Thanks, @TheGreatDuck.  I think that sleeping on it is the best idea.  The challenge for me is that my impatience builds up to get feedback but perhaps, memory of this event will be enough to get me to wait a day or two.  :-)

Comment: @LarryFreeman to be frank, I think Math stack exchange is only intended for questions that actually serve some purpose in futhering mathematics in a more significant way than a random idle question someone asks. It's possible that's where the disconnect lies. Granted, this is my personal opinion. My opinion is that only questions with some value are worth asking. Of course, I am probably very very very wrong on this.

Comment: I agree and offer one additional observation: unless you have mathematical talent, it is often difficult to distinguish between what appears to a marhematician to be an idle, random question and a question well worth asking. I am so happy for this site because it allows a foolish amateur like me to get help understanding classic proofs and to see my own foolishness in misunderstanding a pattern or concept. This has given me glimpses into some of the very deep patterns of number theory. Thank you so much for tour comments. The members of this site are the source of its great value! :-)